# How to set the minimum SDK Build Tools version required in an Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

When I try to run my React Native project in the Android emulator I get the following error:

> The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.1) is too low for project ':app'.
>   Minimum required is 25.0.0

My `android/app/build.gradle` file specifies:

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

On Android Studio, it also logs the same error for each of the packages I'm using:

[image: Errors within Android Studio]

I believe this started happening after I inadvertently updated some stuff that Android Studio suggested.

All the `build.gradle` files that I've checked specify version `23.0.1`, but for some reason `25.0.0` seems to be overriding that setting.

How do I go about correcting this?

Comment: Install Build Tool Version 25.0.0,just click on that link in Error log that will download and install requirements

Answer (score 4):

Ran into this issue and realized that the error is quite vague. Coming from an iOS background into React Native, I've had to learn a lot more about the Android ecosystem. The problem is that your project Gradle version is too high.

In your project's (top level) `build.gradle` you may be using:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'`

Gradle v2.3.1, implicitly sets the minimum SDK Build Tools revision to 25.0.0.

To fix, you can simply revert back to:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'`

This will allow your project's modules to use buildToolsVersions `23.0.1` or `25.0.2`

Answer (score 1):

1. Install required `Build Tools version 25.0.0`
2. Update `buildToolsVersion` in `build.gradle` file and `sync` project
3. Set `compileSdkVersion 25` and `targetSdkVersion 25`
4. `Clean` and `Build` your project again
5. Finally, `Run` on device

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

May be you are updated your studio version and open your old project if you do that then you want to go to package explorer app and right click on it and open modual setting one window open then select the project and set the Gradle version 
and android plugin version

example 
My studio version is 2.3
then Gradle version = 3.3
and Android plugin version = 2.3.0

if you not find then create new project blank project and see the setting and apply on your project

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK Build Tools are required to build Android apps (see https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/index.html#tools-build). It's recommended to always use the latest version.

In your case `react*` libraries aren't compatible with current build tools version (23.0.1) so you need to upgrade (25.0.2 is the latest version at the moment).

The version is specified in `build.gradle` of your module. After syncing project everything would be fine or an error will be displayed that will suggest installing the missing version. Android Studio will do that for you.

```
android {
  ...
  buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
```

Comment: Each of the third party packages I am using specify `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"` in their own `build.gradle`. I can't really change those, because they're third party modules. I tried changing the app's `buildToolsVersion` to `25.0.2`, but then i start getting errors from each third party package.

Comment: In fact, after changing the app's buildToolsVersion to 25.0.2, the error still states that the minimum version is 25.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall all new-ones 'Android SDK Build-Tools' versions after comes 23.0.1 in SDK Manager and Sync and try again for that project only...

Comment: After doing this, it still complains that the minimum version is 25.0.0

Comment: @thatjuan  Forget to mention after that It is always better to clean and rebuild project.