# After adding new RN package I get "The SDK Build Tools revision is too low for project"

Tags: react-native

I don't understand what's going on here. I added a new package to my react-native app with these commands:

```
yarn add react-native-version-number
react-native link
```

Now when I do `react-native run-android` I get this error:

> The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.1) is too low for project
>   ':react-native-version-number'. Minimum required is 25.0.0

Does this mean the package I'm adding requires SDK Tools 25.0.0 or higher? Or does it mean my app requires packages that use SDK Tools > 25.0.0? Because in my app/build/build.gradle file I have:

```
...
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"
...
```

The build.gradle file for react-native-version-number contains this:

```
...
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
...
```

I found that if I modify this to say "26.0.3" then that error goes away but I get the same error on a different package that was working before. It doesn't seem like I should have to modify package files. Apparently when I ran `yarn add` it must have changed something in my app to require a higher version of SDK Tools. How do I fix this?

Note: I'm on Windows and I'm not using Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add the following script to you `android/build.gradle` (not `android/app/build.gradle`).

This section will force all the libraries to use defined versions of compileSDK and buildTools:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 26
                buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43954560/1715240

Basically I had to edit my top-level `build.gradle` file and change this line to use Gradle v2.2.3

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```